# pass data from spring boot controller to Boostrap modal

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, bootstrap-modal

I have an autocomplete field in my modal which is populated from the controller, when I select an option from the suggestions the controller loads details from the database for the selected individual, how can I pass that data from the controller to the modal page. IN other words il'd like to update my modal page with data returned from controller. for example ild like to pass name to the modal and set it on name field without refreshing the whole modal

CONTROLLER

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchstudent", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute(value="foo") Foo foo,Model model) {

             model.addAttribute("name", "name");

        return "accounts/accountshome :: popup1";
    
}
```

```html
<div id="popup1" th:fragment="popup1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
                    
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Fee payment</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
                    
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                              
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="card card-profile">                                                                       
                            <div  class="card-body">                                
                                        
                                <div class="form-group">                                          
                                  <div class="serchadmcontainer" id="serchadmcontainer">
                                      <form action="#" th:action="@{/searchstudent}" th:object="${foo}" method="post">
                                         <input  id="autocomplete-ajax" type="text"  th:field="*{bar}" class="form-control"/>                         
                                      </form>
                                  </div>
                                </div>                                      
                                          
                                  <h4  class="card-title"></h4>               
                                  <h6 th:text="${classs}" class="card-category text-gray"></h6>
                                  <h2 class="card-category text-orange" style="font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline;"></h2>
                                          

                                </div>                                      
                              </div>
                            </div>                      
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
                
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a   class="stretched-link mr-auto">Previous Receipts</a>                                                       
                <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Process</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put the -must be updated- content in a fragment inside a div, then make a get petition to the controller that returns the fragment, and use the returned html to substitute the contents of the div that contains your fragment.

Comment: Like substituting the fragments?